# Skip numeric keyboard enter button with javascript or html

Tags: javascript, android, keyboard, enter, keyup

My end goal is overriding the enter button on the numeric keyboard to close the keyboard.

I have an input field that I eventually want a user to enter a phone number in. therefore, I set it up like this, which I surrounded the input by a form to try to override the enter button (I'm using angular):

```
<form ng-submit="closeKeyboard()">
    <input id="myInput">
</form>
```

This is successful in overriding the enter key and closing the keyboard instead. Next, I want just the numeric keyboard, so I updated my input:

```
<input id="myInput" type="tel" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}">
```

This is successful in bringing up the numeric keyboard (yes, I know that setting the type as numeric or number (can't remember which) works too). However, now the enter button is not overridden. So I tried to set it up to have a keyup listener to ignore the enter button:

```
elem.keyup(function (event) {
    var x = event.keyCode;
    var y = event.which;
    if (x == 13 || y == 13) {
        $element.find(":input").blur();
    }
});
```

This is successful in catching *many* of the keys. When I type the '5' and '6' keys on the numeric keyboard, it is successful. Except when I click the enter button on the numeric keyboard, it instead jumps to the next input field on the screen. Please help!
PS, I'm testing this out on a Nexus 9, and am using Chrome's remote debugger through the developer tools. When I type the enter key through the remote debugger, it successfully reads 13 for the keycode.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer. On the numeric keyboard on the Nexus 9 (not sure about the other tablets), the 'enter' button is really the tab button.
This was confusing because I could register a keydown for that button press, but NOT a keyup, which is what I had been checking for before. So I changed to a keydown, and added '9' to my '13' check, and that worked!

Comment: Also, call event.preventDefault() to stop the natural tab content too